# show image in j2me from web service

Tags: php, xml, image, java-me

I am making a quiz application in J2ME. Questions and answers will come from web service as XML format which is made by PHP. The questions and option contain both image(relative path) and string(question). If I put address of images in web services, it will ask user for network access in every question, because every question contains image. It will affect user interaction and if I put these images in byte format it will be critical to plot them as image and I also got problem to convert image in byte array, which can be read from J2ME devices.
So, how could I put image in xml web service to solve this problem. Any suggestion will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will prefer to store image path in xml like http://car.amarhost.net/blogo/00001.png. So that you don't have to store image in local storage and if you have a large number of image, you can download them asynchronously